# get service worker id or date from within service worker

Tags: service-worker

Does anybody know if there is a way to get this number or date inside the service worker:

[image: chrome debug tools screenshot of service worker info]

It would be handy to name my service worker cache either `cache-1182` or `cache-20171127171448`

I guess the received date must be known before the install event.

Comment: Hmm. Am I missing something or should you be just generating the cache name (string) as a part of your build process and SW generation?

Comment: Well that's how they tell you to do it (and how I am doing it now) but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: Ahh, ok. What's the problem? I mean, if you have a build process that any way handles all the asset generation, naming, etc., it does the cache string changing automatically, right? What could be made easier?

Comment: Well the browser already calculates if there has been a change to the service worker, so it's too bad that the build process also has to work that out.  Also it is hard to get the webpack hashes into the javascript code.  So although there are a lot of solutions available, if there were a way to get that information, and if somebody knew it would be really useful for a lot of things.  It would also be useful to know for sure if it is impossible.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I understand. I hope you're using a plugin such as Workbox to ease your build steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this thing does not exist in the [Service Worker specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/) so we must assume it is an internal implementation detail of Google Chrome, thus unaccessible.

To simplify, you might use installation timestamp as the version number and then look for cached resources in the cache marked with the newest timestamp. You can inspect all the cache keys with `caches.keys()`.