# What kind of information service worker has about itself?

Tags: url, metadata, service-worker

I wanted to ask "How to get the location of the service worker from the inside service worker?" but I've found this question [get service worker id or date from within service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47648808/387194), I was looking at the spec but didn't found anything useful.

So my question is are there any information about the service worker from inside the worker. Or to have any metadata I need to post a message to the worker.

I'm interested in the URL of the worker or the URL of the website where the worker was installed since I need this URL for routing inside the worker.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a location inside service worker that points to the URL of the worker filename.

To the path of the root where worker was installed (which is what I need) you can use:

```js
const root_url = location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '');
```